# Android JNI - How to properly release memory allocated in C native functions

Tags: android, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, native

I use alot of memory allocations in C in my Android app.

To avoid any memory leaks i want to better understand how JAVA garbage collector frees memory that is no longer in use.

When variables are allocated in JAVA it is obvious that GC can clear it. but when allocations are made within a C function, i have read in other posts that JAVA may sometimes not be sure if the variable is still in use or not, and it will never be cleared resulting in a mem leak.

Please feel free to comment with **any info that will enrich our understanding of memory allocationand freeing in C native functions**. I have also added 2 examples of code that I would like to have your opinion of.

Thanks everyone!

Examples:

**Code 1** - surely new_string isnt a memory leak, will java be able to garbage-collect str_to_return?

```
jstring
Java_com_example_adhocktest_SenderUDP_SendUdpJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz)
{
    char * new_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
        jstring str_to_return = (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, new_string);

        free(new_string);
    return (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, str_to_return);
}
```

** Code 2**  - is it possible to return new_string directly as we do here? we suspect that there would be a mem leak

```
jstring
Java_com_example_adhocktest_SenderUDP_SendUdpJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz)
{
    char * new_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*200);

    return (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, new_string );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using NewStringUTF which returns new_string as a jstring.  The routine has no idea how new_string was allocated so it does not attempt to free it.  The caller of the routine is responsible for freeing new_string if that is what is required to fix a memory leak.

```
/* free required here */
char* heap_string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
strcpy(heap_string, "This is a heap string");
jstring retstr = (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, heap_string);
free(heap_string);
return retstr;
```

If it is a constant,

```
/* free not required */
jstring retstr = (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, "Cannot be freed");
return retstr;
```

If the string was created on the stack

```
/* free not required */
const char* stack_string = "on the stack";
jstring retstr = (*env1)->NewStringUTF(env1, stack_string);
return retstr;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
So if i understand correctly , the jstring of the last example you gave will be freed by JAVA since it is the caller to the function?

Comment: Yes - the j-types will be freed by Java.

Comment: `const char* stack_string` only puts the pointer on the stack; you want `const char stack_string[]` instead.